# Solutions to a 5th order, linear ODE with complex coefficients.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working on a research project, and I have come across a situation where I need to find the solution form of a 5th order ODE with some complex coefficients.  In general, the solutions to the characteristic equation are 5 complex numbers with no conjugate pairs among them.  I would assume that the solution would be just the complex exponentials of these five complex eigenvalues, but something seems to be wrong in my later analysis.  Am I wrong that this would be the solution form?

Edit: Here is the equation:

$$
c\phi^{v}-(\gamma+1)\phi^{iv}-c(a^2+1)\phi'''+[(\gamma+1)(a^2+1)-2\alpha(aA-1)]\phi''+ca^2\phi'-[a^2(\gamma+1)+2\alpha a(a-A)]\phi=0.
$$

I am choosing values for $a$, $\alpha$, $A$, $c$, and $\gamma$ beforehand.  All values except for $\gamma$ are real.  I am currently using the values $c\approx 0.08832860463431712$ (solution to another system), $a=1.5$, $A=2.25$, $\alpha=0.04$, and $\gamma=x+iy \in\mathbb{C}$ where $x\in[-3,1]$ and $y\in[-1,1]$.  I am using this equation to study the stability of a traveling front solution using an Evans function.  I need the solution forms for this ODE to construct this Evans function.

I have solutions for when $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$, using general ODE theory by finding characteristic values, forming exponential solutions with those characteristic values, and everything seems to work fine.  When I let $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$, I don't get solutions that agree on the real line with my previous solution set.

Comment: (assuming scalar ODE) solutions to $\sum_{j=0}^{5} a_{j}x^{(j)}(t) = 0$ are of the form $\sum_{j=1}^{5} c_{j}e^{\lambda_{j}t}$ as long as the $\lambda_{j}$ roots of the characteristic equation $\sum_{j=0}^{5} a_{j}r^{j}=0$ are distinct... if not, say $(r-\lambda_{1})^{k}=0$, then solution is $e^{\lambda_{1}t} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} c_{1,j}x^{j}$.

Comment: if you gave something more explicit... and how you got something "wrong" later on, it may help us guide you